# Post Chatter on Field Change on Update

Tags: trigger, feeditem

Can someone help me nail the syntax on chattering on a field update?

```
 trigger ChatterCoverageUpdate on Account (before update) {

  List<FeedItem> feedItems = new List<FeedItem>();

for ( Account t : Trigger.new) {
        if (Condition to See if Field Coverage_Update__c has Changed) 

{
            FeedItem fitem = new FeedItem();
            fitem.type = 'TextPost';
            fitem.ParentId = t.id;

            fitem.Body =  t.Coverage_Update__c        ;


            {
            feedItems.add(fitem);
            }
        }
    }
 if (feedItems.size() > 0) {
        Database.insert(feedItems,false); //notice the false value. This will allow some to fail if Chatter isn't available on that object
    }

}
```

Also does this need to be before or after update to work? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, code snippet you need for Chatter :

```
//Adding a Text post
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = oId; //eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
insert post;

//Adding a Link post
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = oId; //eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
post.LinkUrl = 'http://www.someurl.com';
insert post;

//Adding a Content post
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = oId; //eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
post.ContentData = base64EncodedFileData;
post.ContentFileName = 'sample.pdf';
insert post;
```

[You can also refer this URL for more information on posting chatter message using Apex.](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes) In you case Chatter message should be in After trigger.

I would suggest to use Process builder, where you can add Chatter message without any need of Trigger or code. [You can refer this tutorial on same.](https://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-13-post-to-chatter/)

Comment: ISCHANGED will be available in next release for Process Builder. I think I will go this route.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ConnectAPI Batch Input to do this - example from docs below and [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_batch.htm):

```
trigger postFeedItemToAccount on Account (after insert) {
    Account[] accounts = Trigger.new;

    // Bulk post to the account feeds.

    List<ConnectApi.BatchInput> batchInputs = new List<ConnectApi.BatchInput>();

    for (Account a : accounts) {
        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();

        input.subjectId = a.id;

        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput body = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
        body.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        textSegment.text = 'Let\'s win the ' + a.name + ' account.';

        body.messageSegments.add(textSegment);
        input.body = body;

        ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(input);
        batchInputs.add(batchInput);
    }

    ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), batchInputs);
}
```